# How can I Filter a list of S4 objects conditional on TRUE/FALSE statement in another list

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements, filtering

I have a list of S4 objects from the rpact package that I want to filter conditionally on TRUE/FALSE statements from another list. The objective is to return a list of S4 objects that is filtered based on the TRUE/FALSE statements in the other list (i.e., only return the S4 objects with a matching TRUE statement).

```
install.packages("rpact")
library(rpact)

# list with S4 objects
list1 <- list(getDesignGroupSequential(sided = 1, alpha = 0.025, informationRates = c(0.33, 0.67, 1), typeOfDesign = "OF"),
              getDesignGroupSequential(sided = 1, alpha = 0.025, informationRates = c(0.33, 0.67, 1), typeOfDesign = "OF"),
              getDesignGroupSequential(sided = 1, alpha = 0.025, informationRates = c(0.33, 0.67, 1), typeOfDesign = "OF"))

list2 <- list(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

I tried using `mappy` as you would when using lists containing datasets. This however produced the following error: *Error in x[y == TRUE] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable*

```
# mapply function
list3 <- mapply(function(x, y) x[y == TRUE], list1, list2)
```

Do you know how to tackle this problem? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `list1[unlist(list2)]` should work fine. Your `mapply` is attempting to filter the objects inside `list1`, not `list1` itself. But if I understand correctly you want a subset of `list1`, and it doesn't matter what `list1` contains.

Comment: @GregorThomas This is actually what I meant. Never knew it would be this simple. Thanks for your help, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
list3 <- list1[list2 == TRUE]
```

Comment: This answer should be more descriptive explaining what the code does to be accepted.